Getting the pitch of the microphone input Godot
I'm making a game for children learning instruments where I need to get the tone currently being played into the microphone.
I've tried figuring out
spectrum_analyzer.get_magnitude_for_frequency_range

but I'm just getting confused. If anyone has done something similar to this in the past, I'd be so happy if you could share your solution. Thanks :)

maybe this will help?

This is somewhat old, but I believe it should help: How to get current Microphone Frequency in Godot.
